# javascript onmouseover+onmouseout and relation between 2 divs

Tags: javascript, css

I´m trying to make a function to show a button when mouseover and hide when mouseout.
The following example will show what´s my problem.

```
------------------------------------------------------------


 ---------
| button2 |           DIV#1                 Button1
|         |
| DIV#2   |
|         |
----------------------------------------------------------
|         |
-----------

**The CSS** 
#div1{

    height: 200px;
    width:500px;
    position: relative;
}
#div2{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    left: 19px;
    top: 76px;
    position: absolute;
}


**Javascript**
$("#button1").hide();
$("#button2").hide();

$('#div1').mouseover(function() {
$("#button1").show();
});

$('#div1').mouseout(function() {
$("#button1").hide();
});

$('#div2').mouseover(function() {
$("#button2").show();
});

$('#div2').mouseout(function() {
$("#button2").hide();
});
```

**HTML** 
Actually there´re lots of elements in my document. But to make it easy to see:

```
<div id='div1'>  <div id='div2'>example button2 </div> example button1 </div>
```

**The problem is :**

When mouseover on DIV#2 the Button1 also show. It seem like this 2 divs has relation to each other.
How to fix this problem in order to make the Buttun1 show only when mouseover the DIV#1.

I have tried to use z-index, but doesn´t help.

Comment: Can you add the HTML as well?

Comment: It abit difficult because I have so many elements there. But anyway I have update, please see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `div2` is on top of `div1`, the problem is when you take mouse on the area where both divs overlap, both divs get the mouseover event. You can stop event propagation on `#div2` so that the mouse over doesn't bubble down to the underlying `div1` hen mouse enters over `div2` and goes into the overlapping area.

```
$('#div2').mouseover(function(event) {
    $("#button2").show();
    event.stopPropagation();// this will stop mouseover on other div
});
```

Similarly, you may want to add code to remove `button1` when the mouse goes from `div1` to `div2` without leaving unerlying `div1` i.e. the overlapping area.

```
$('#div2').mouseover(function(event) {
    $("#button1").hide();
    $("#button2").show();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: So thank you so much, I´ve spent whole day for just these lines.

Answer (score 0):

If div two is a child of div one the hover event on div two is bubbling up to div one. What you would need to do is use event.stopPropagation() to prevent the bubbling:

```
/* CSS */
#button1, #button2 {
    display: none;
}

/* jQuery */

$(function() {

    $('#div2').hover(
        function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $('#button2').toggle();
        },
        function(event) {    
            event.stopPropagation();   
            $('#button2').toggle();
        });

    $('#div1').hover(
        function() {
            $('#button1).toggle();
        },
        function() {
            $('#button2').toggle();
        });


});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Even though I got the answer but this one also nice to try. I want to keep both answer for my education. Thank you again.